# Testing a component's state after an async fetch with Jest & Enzyme (using module)

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, mocking, enzyme, jestjs

I'm trying to test a React component's state with Jest.
On ComponentDidUpdate, it fetches the username on the server if someone is logged in and updates the state.user with the username.
If no user is logged in, it switches state.pleaseLogin to true.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import "whatwg-fetch";
import LoggedInNav from "./LoggedInNav";
import LoggedOutNav from "./LoggedOutNav";
import urls from "../../urls";
import getUser from "../fetch/getUser";

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null,
      pleaseLogin: false
    };
    this.handleGetUser = this.handleGetUser.bind(this);
  }

  handleGetUser() {
    getUser().then(res => {
      if (res.hasOwnProperty("username")) {
        this.setState({
          user: res.username
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          pleaseLogin: true
        });
      }
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleGetUser();
  }

  render() {
    let nav;
    if (this.state.user) {
      nav = <LoggedInNav user={this.state.user} />;
    } else if (this.state.pleaseLogin) {
      nav = <LoggedOutNav />;
    } else {
      nav = null;
    }
    return (
      <header className="app-header">
        <h1 className="header-brand">Watchers</h1>
        {nav}
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the code for the getUser() that fetches username on the server:

```
export default () => {
  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/user/user_data`, {
    credentials: "include"
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    });
};
```

I mocked the API call manually. The file is called 'getUser.js' and is in a **mocks** folder, next to the original 'getUser.js' like so:

```
export default () => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    username: 'Username'
  })
}
```

And then the test:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Header from "../react/components/Header";
import getUser from "../react/fetch/getUser";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

jest.mock("../react/fetch/getUser");
const wrapper = mount(<Header />);

describe("<Header/>", () => {
  describe("component class", () => {
    it("should update state.user after componentDidMount()", () => {
      return getUser().then(() => {
        expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({
          user: "Username",
          pleaseLogin: false
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The test passes, the state changed like intended with state.user now equal to "Username".
If I change my mock module and make it return an empty object, it works as well and state.pleaseLogin switches to true. However I have to do it manually to test both cases.
I tried to mock those two different implementations directly in my test file with jest.mock('...module', () => {}), and with jest.doMock('...module', () => {}) but the state does not update when I run the test; while it did with the manual mock. I am not sure where the issue comes from, maybe this has something to do with asynchronicity or with mocking in Jest?

Answer (score 2):

I found two different ways to test this.

The manual mock might not be the best solution here since the mocked module contains only a function. However here is how I wrote the test:

*1. Manual mock in the **__mocks__** folder*

```
// In the example, the function getUser is exported with 'export default'.
module.exports = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({}))


// If the function is exported with 'export const getUser = () => {}':
module.exports = {
    getUser: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({}))
}
```

**Test**

```
jest.mock("../react/fetch/getUser");
const getUser = require("../react/fetch/getUser");

// If function exported with 'export const getUser = () => {}':
// const {getUser} = require("../react/fetch/getUser");

describe("<Header/>", () => {
  it("should update state.user after componentDidMount()", () => {

    getUser.mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({ username: "Username" })
    );

    const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);

    expect.assertions(1);

    return (
      getUser()
        .then(() => {
          expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({
            user: "Username",
            pleaseLogin: false
          });
        })
    );
  });

  it("should update state.pleaseLogin after componentDidMount()", () => {
    getUser.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({}));
    const wrapper = mount(<Header />);
    return (
      getUser()
        .then(() => {
          expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({
            user: null,
            pleaseLogin: true
          });
        })
    );
  });
});
```

*2. Creating a **mock function** to use in test code*

**Test**

```
// If function exported with 'export default'
jest.mock("../react/fetch/getUser", () => jest.fn());
const getUser = require("../react/fetch/getUser");

// Else
// jest.mock("../react/fetch/getUser", () => ({getUser: jest.fn()}));
// const {getUser} = require("../react/fetch/getUser")

describe("<Header/>", () => {
  it("should update state.user after componentDidMount()", () => {
    const promise = Promise.resolve({
      username: "Username"
    });
    getUser.mockImplementation(() => promise);

    const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);

    expect.assertions(1);
    return getUser().then(() => {
      expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({
        user: "Username",
        pleaseLogin: false
      });
    });
  });
});
```

*A few things worth noting:*

- mock inside test

I tried to use mock and doMock inside the test unsuccessfully. It might be related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582

- MockImplementation

> The mockImplementation method is useful when you need to define the
>   default implementation of a mock function that is created from another
>   module

However mockImplementationOnce() will throw an error in this test

- Enzyme shallow()/mount()

Enzyme shallow() or mount() have to be called after the mock in order to use the implementation. Otherwise we get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'

- return promise

The promise needs to be returned. if no 'return', expectations in 'then' will just be skipped since we do not wait for the async call to return.

> [Jest Docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#promises): "Be sure to return the promise - if you omit this return
>   statement, your test will complete before fetchData completes."

You can check the following link to see what happens if return is omitted: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1924